# What is operator new(unsigned int)?

Tags: disassembly, c++, gcc

In the disassembler output (ARM) I see:

```
    BLX _Znwj
```

where `BLX` is ARM procedure call and `_Znwj` is demangled as

```
$ c++filt  _Znwj
operator new(unsigned int)
```

What does that `operator new` do? Is it `new` or `new[]`?
What type does it return?
How do I explicitly call it from C++, something in the `operator+(a,b)` style?

(I know that it is possible to define `operator new` in a class, but this looks a bit different.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A runtime function does not necessarily convert to a C++ function. For example, on a processor that has no floating point hardware, a simple statement like

```
a=b+c;
```

with `a`, `b` and `c` being floats, will probably be converted to a function call that takes `b` and `c` as parameters and returns the results. The user is not supposed to call that function directly.

In your case, consider that every `new` probably maps to something that allocates memory and calls a constructor function, and every `new[]` allocates memory for several elements and calls a constructor function on each element. The `new` `_Znwj` function is the memory allocator used internally by the `new` operator (at least if you're using `gcc`, which I assume), and it's not intended to be called directly from C++.

This program:

```
    class Foo {
            int bar;
    };

    int main(void) {
            Foo *baz=new Foo();
            Foo *var=new Foo[20];
    }
```

Compiles to (try `gcc -S`):

```
    stmfd   sp!, {fp, lr}
    .save {fp, lr}
    .setfp fp, sp, #4
    add     fp, sp, #4
    .pad #8
    sub     sp, sp, #8
    mov     r0, #4                <-- 4 bytes for single variable
    bl      _Znwj
    mov     r3, r0                <-- r0 returns the pointer to the allocated memory
    mov     r2, #0
    str     r2, [r3]
    str     r3, [fp, #-8]
    mov     r0, #80               <-- 80 bytes (20*4) for array
    bl      _Znaj
    mov     r3, r0                <-- r0 returns the pointer to the allocated memory
    str     r3, [fp, #-12]
    mov     r3, #0
    mov     r0, r3
    sub     sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {fp, lr}
    bx      lr
```

So, you see that the `_Znwj` resp. `_Znaj` are the allocator functions for a single class resp. an array of classes, both of them take the number of bytes required as parameter, and both of them return a pointer to the allocated memory as result.

To answer your questions:

1. **What does that operator `new` do ?**

   It allocates memory for a new class instance.
2. **Is it `new` or `new[]` ?**

   `_Znwj` is `new`, and `_Znaj` is `new[]`.
3. **What type does it return ?**

   It returns the address of the newly allocated memory block. In C++, the closest match to resemble that would be a `void *`, but note it's supposed to point to a class structure.
4. **How do I explicitly call it from C++, something in the `operator+(a,b)` style ?**

   You're not supposed to do that. You use `new` or `new[]`. I assume the makers of `gcc` explicitly used a function name that cannot, normally, be called from a C++ program without a syntax error due to the name conflict.

Comment: In fact, `void*x=operator new(4);` compiles and generates the same code as `int*x=new(int);`

Answer (score 1):

This is called "placement `new`" and was introduced in C++03.  The way it works is that one can have, say a C++ class around a set of hardware registers and then use *placement `new`* to put the class exactly atop those hardware registers.  For example, if a hardware-based hardware Random Number Generator (RNG) is defined using 32-bit Control Register, Status Register and Data Register all starting at offset 0x50000600, you could define a class:

```
class RNG_class
{
private:
  volatile uint32_t CR;  // set to 1 to enable
  volatile uint32_t SR;  // low bit set when next num available
  volatile uint32_t DR:
public;
  RNG_class() : CR(1) {} 
  uint32_t next() { while (SR&1 == 0); return DR; }
};
```

Elsewhere, then one can instantiate this class as

```
RNG_class RNG* = new(0x50000600) RNG_class();
```

And one can use it as:

```
r = RNG->next();
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new) for more information.